# How to select rows with a particular rank per partition?

Tags: mysql, partitioning, window-functions

I want to pick the row with the highest value in a column based on partitioning on another column. The problem is to pick the highest-earning employees from each department, click [here](https://leetcode.com/problems/department-highest-salary) for the complete problem.

The tables are:

1. Employee table:

```
+----+-------+--------+--------------+
| Id | Name  | Salary | DepartmentId |
+----+-------+--------+--------------+
| 1  | Joe   | 70000  | 1            |
| 2  | Jim   | 90000  | 1            |
| 3  | Henry | 80000  | 2            |
| 4  | Sam   | 60000  | 2            |
| 5  | Max   | 90000  | 1            |
+----+-------+--------+--------------+
```

2. The Department table:

```
+----+----------+
| Id | Name     |
+----+----------+
| 1  | IT       |
| 2  | Sales    |
+----+----------+
```

The objective is to pick employees who have the highest salary in each of the departments.

My query:

```
select department, employee, salary 
from (select e.name as employee, d.name as department, e.salary as salary, rank() over(partition by d.name order by salary desc) as salary_rank 
      from employee e 
      join department d on e.departmentid=d.id 
      group by d.id 
      having salary_rank=1) temp;
```

Error:

> You cannot use the alias 'salary_rank' of an expression containing a window function in this context.'

How can I use a particular rank in the `having` clause in order to get the highest ranking employee in each department?

I am using the where clause that works:

```
select department, employee, salary 
from (select e.name as employee, d.name as department, e.salary as salary, rank() over(partition by d.name order by salary desc) as salary_rank 
      from employee e 
      join department d on e.departmentid=d.id) temp 
where salary_rank=1;
```

but I wanted to use the `having` clause.

I have tried reading the documentation and watched a couple of tutorials, all of them use the having clause for ranking per partition. What am I missing here?

Comment: *How can I use a particular rank in the having clause in order to get the highest ranking employee in each department?* Noway. Window function is calculated over final rowset, after HAVING is applied. PS. If you may use window function then you may use CTE - move your subquery to it.

Answer (score 1):

Window functions have some limitation for example you cannot use them in `HAVING`.

> You can only use window functions in the `SELECT` list and `ORDER BY` clauses of a query.

Window functions are listed in the `SELECT` list (between the two keywords `SELECT` and `FROM`) at the same place where usual functions, expressions and columns are listed. They contain the keyword `OVER`.

The definition :

```
-- Window functions appear between the key words SELECT and FROM
SELECT   ...,
         <window_function>,
         ...
FROM     <tablename>
...
;
```

And in mysql [WINDOW functions restriction](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-restrictions.html) is written:

> Using such functions in a subquery of these statements (to select rows) is permitted.

So your approach is correct. You have to put the `SELECT` in a subquery or as Akina said you can use cte, which is only another FROM. Then you can have the `salary_rank = 1` condition in the `WHERE` clause of the main query.

Your query has to be

```
select department, employee, salary 
from (select e.name as employee, d.name as department, e.salary as salary, rank() over(partition by d.name order by salary desc) as salary_rank 
      from employee e 
      join department d on e.departmentid=d.id 
      ) temp
WHERE salary_rank=1;
```

Comment: I did not get your answer. Can you write the final query?

Comment: sure i added the query